# Javascript: How to hide div if Label inside is empty

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to hide the div with the class= "form-group" if the label inside doesn't have anything to display
here is my html code:

```
echo'<div class="form-group">';
                        echo'<label for="exampleInputFile" class="tbh">'.$query2['req_1'].'</label>';
                        echo'<input type="file" name="my_image" accept="image/*" id="exampleInputFile"> ';
                        echo'</div>';
```

And my javascript is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        if($('label.tbh:empty')){
                            $('div.form-group').hide();
                        }
                        </script>
```

Is there any other way to do that? In my code it doesn't seem to work.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: All answers are useful not only to me but to the viewers too. +1 to all whom answered. I appreciated your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, you may do it by that way:

```
$("div.form-group label.tbh:empty").parent().hide();
```

It's a right way to do in inside `document.ready` callback:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.form-group label.tbh:empty").parent().hide()
});
```

To include jQuery, add

```
echo '<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>';
```

to head of your script.

But it seems like you are using PHP or something like at your backend side?
If so, you may do it on server-side code like this:

```
if(strlen($query2['req_1']) == 0)
{
    echo'<div class="form-group">';
    echo'<label for="exampleInputFile" class="tbh">'.$query2["req_1"].'</label>';
    echo'<input type="file" name="my_image" accept="image/*" id="exampleInputFile"> ';
    echo'</div>';
}
```

in this case you would not transfer unneeded data to the client.

Comment: Thanks @MobDev the jQuery  worked perfectly. And the PHP too but the PHP is quite tricky. It really helped man thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `.text()` is a safer option. If the label is empty, `.text()` will return an empty string and negating it will give `true`. Refer to the interactive snippet with example below. I placed the relevant code in a button click handler to prove that it works after you click on it.

```js
$('button').click(function () {
  if (!$('.tbh').text()){
    $('.form-group').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputFile" class="tbh"></label>
<input type="file" name="my_image" accept="image/*" id="exampleInputFile"></div>

<button>Click to hide</button>
```

Comment: Thanks it works but what if I want to hide it automatically with no button needed.

Comment: I put it in a button to prove that it works after you click on it in the example. You can simply just use the code within the button function for your use case.

Comment: Thanks man I'm gonna play around with it. +1 Your answer is useful to the viewers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if($('label.tbh').html() == ""){
     $('div.form-group').hide();
  }
```

Comment: I gives a console error it says: Uncaught ReferrenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Try jQuery instated of $  now if you got jQuery is not defined then check proper version of Jquery is loaded or not ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
/* Be sure that your dom is loaded */    
$( document ).ready(function() {
    /* Checking that the label is empty */
    if($("label").html().length == 0) {
        $('div.form-group').hide();   
    }
});
```

You can also use `size()` instead of `length`.